# How can I deploy Apache, Rails App, and phpMyAdmin on the same Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, phpmyadmin

now I'm running rails app on Apache.
My rails app is placed at /var/www/html/railsapp/ and its written in httpd.conf.
It completely works fine and show app when I access to http://example.com/

One more thing that I want is "phpMyAdmin" beside rails app.
phpMyAdmin is currently installed at /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

I created phpMyAdmin.conf in /etc/httpd/conf.d in which, I wrote those below

```
Alias /phpmyadmin/ "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/">
  Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
  AcceptPathInfo On
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

After restarted Apache, it still shows rail's routing error when I try to access http://example.com/phpmyadmin

It seems rails recognize "phpmyadmin" part as rail's controller name.
Can anyone help me about this?

I want to access to phpmyadmin when I go to example.com/phpmyadmin
and I wanna access to rails app when I go to example.com

Thanks!!

Comment: please use proper text formatting. Indent your code with four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at **[this](http://macdiggs.com/2007/06/29/using-php-inside-rails-structure-on-apache/)**

To sum it up, you have to modify your httpd.conf :

- set rewrite rules on
- set up an url rewrite condition that matches requests on your php file
- have a rewrite rule to let default server rules handle the request, instead of rails' router

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when I Added the below line in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysql.yourservername.com
<Directory "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```